# how to return the view if I need to use return response()->json datatables and laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I used datatables and date range filter to get results and if I don't use return response()->json I get this "localhost indique:DataTables warning: table id=sampleTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/1"  and if I make start date and end date and click filter I get "DataTables warning: table id=sampleTable - Invalid JSON response" and I get the correct result in devtools/Network/preview but not in view in admin/reports/revenue but if I used return response()->json I don't get the view and I get:

```
{
  "currentAdminMenu":"report",
  "exports":{"xlsx":"Excel File","pdf":"PDF File"},
  "currentAdminSubMenu":"report-revenue",
  "startDate":"2022-05-01",
  "endDate":"2022-05-31",
  "revenues":[]
}
```

So how do I get the result and I want to understand how response()->json works and thank you very much

**reportController**:

```
public function revenue(Request $request)
    {
        $this->data['currentAdminSubMenu'] = 'report-revenue';

        $startDate = $request->input('start');
        $endDate = $request->input('end');

        if ($startDate && !$endDate) {
            \Session::flash('error', 'The end date is required if the start date is present');
            return redirect('admin/reports/revenue');
        }

        if (!$startDate && $endDate) {
            \Session::flash('error', 'The start date is required if the end date is present');
            return redirect('admin/reports/revenue');
        }

        if ($startDate && $endDate) {
            if (strtotime($endDate) < strtotime($startDate)) {
                \Session::flash('error', 'The end date should be greater or equal than start date');
                return redirect('admin/reports/revenue');
            }

            $earlier = new \DateTime($startDate);
            $later = new \DateTime($endDate);
            $diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");
            
            if ($diff >= 31) {
                \Session::flash('error', 'The number of days in the date ranges should be lower or equal to 31 days');
                return redirect('admin/reports/revenue');
            }
        } else {
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
            $startDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($currentDate));
            $endDate = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($currentDate));
        }
        $this->data['startDate'] = $startDate;
        $this->data['endDate'] = $endDate;

        $sql = " 
        SELECT order_date,
         COUNT(*) AS num_of_orders,
         SUM(grand_total) AS gross_revenue,
         SUM(tax_amount) AS taxes_amount,
         SUM(shipping_cost) AS shipping_amount,
         SUM(grand_total - tax_amount - shipping_cost - discount_amount) AS net_revenue
     FROM orders 
   WHERE DATE(order_date) >= :start_date
     AND DATE(order_date) <= :end_date 
     AND status = :status
     AND payment_status = :payment_status
   GROUP BY order_date
   ORDER BY order_date ASC
   ";

        $revenues = \DB::select(
            \DB::raw($sql),
            [
                //'start_date_series' => $startDate,
                //'end_date_series' => $endDate,
                'start_date' => $startDate,
                'end_date' => $endDate,
                'status' => Order::COMPLETED,
                'payment_status' => Order::PAID,
            ]
        );

        $this->data['revenues'] = ($startDate && $endDate) ? $revenues : [];

        if ($exportAs = $request->input('export')) {
            if (!in_array($exportAs, ['xlsx', 'pdf'])) {
                \Session::flash('error', 'Invalid export request');
                return redirect('admin/reports/revenue');
            }

            if ($exportAs == 'xlsx') {
                $fileName = 'report-revenue-'. $startDate .'-'. $endDate .'.xlsx';

                return Excel::download(new ReportRevenueExport($revenues), $fileName);
            }

            if ($exportAs == 'pdf') {
                $fileName = 'report-revenue-'. $startDate .'-'. $endDate .'.pdf';
                $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.reports.exports.revenue_pdf', $this->data);

                return $pdf->download($fileName);
            }
        }

        return view('admin.reports.revenue', $this->data);
        //return response()->json($this->data);
    }
```

filter.blade.php:

```
<form action="" method="" class="input-daterange form-inline" >
 @csrf
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" readonly="" value="{{ !empty(request()->input('start')) ? request()->input('start') : '' }}" name="start" id="start-date" placeholder="from">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" readonly="" value="{{ !empty(request()->input('end')) ? request()->input('end') : '' }}" name="end" id="end-date" placeholder="to">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    
    <select name="export" id="export" class="form-control input-block">
    <option value="{{!empty(request()->input('export')) ? request()->input('export') : null}}" >-- Export to --</option>
     @foreach($exports as $key => $label)
     
     <option value="{{ $key }}"  >{{ $label }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        
        <button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                    <button type="button" name="refresh" id="refresh" class="btn btn-default">Refresh</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

revenue.blade.php:

```
@extends('admin.app')
@section('title') Revenue Report @endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="app-title">
        <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> Revenue Report</h1>
            <p>List of all revenue report</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
                        @include('admin.partials.flashs')
                        
                        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tile">
            
                <div class="tile-body table-responsive">
                @include('admin.reports.filter')
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="sampleTable">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Orders</th>
                                <th>Gross Revenue</th>
                                <th>Taxes</th>
                                <th>Shipping</th>
                                <th>Net Revenue</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @php
                                    $totalOrders = 0;
                                    $totalGrossRevenue = 0;
                                    $totalTaxesAmount = 0;
                                    $totalShippingAmount = 0;
                                    $totalNetRevenue = 0;
                                @endphp
                                @forelse ($revenues as $revenue)
                                    <tr>    
                                        <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($revenue->order_date)->format('Y-m-d')  }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ url('admin/orders?start='. \Carbon\Carbon::parse($revenue->order_date)->format('Y-m-d') .'&end='. \Carbon\Carbon::parse($revenue->order_date)->format('Y-m-d') . '&status=completed') }}">{{ $revenue->num_of_orders }}</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{ $revenue->gross_revenue }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $revenue->taxes_amount }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $revenue->shipping_amount}}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $revenue->net_revenue }}</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    @php
                                        $totalOrders += $revenue->num_of_orders;
                                        $totalGrossRevenue += $revenue->gross_revenue;
                                        $totalTaxesAmount += $revenue->taxes_amount;
                                        $totalShippingAmount += $revenue->shipping_amount;
                                        $totalNetRevenue += $revenue->net_revenue;
                                    @endphp
                                @empty
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6">No records found</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforelse
                                
                                @if ($revenues)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Total</td>
                                        <td><strong>{{ $totalOrders }}</strong></td>
                                        <td><strong>{{ $totalGrossRevenue }}</strong></td>
                                        <td><strong>{{ $totalTaxesAmount }}</strong></td>
                                        <td><strong>{{ $totalShippingAmount }}</strong></td>
                                        <td><strong>{{ $totalNetRevenue }}</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('backend/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('backend/js/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
       
    <!-- Datatables -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/r-2.2.3/datatables.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        load_data();

function load_data(start = '', end = '')
{
 $('#sampleTable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
   // buttons
   "dom": "<'row'<'col-10'r>><'row'<'col-5'l><'col-7 text-right'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'B>><'row'<'col-sm-12't>><'row'<'col-5'i><'col-7'p>>",
                        "buttons": [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
  ajax: {
   url:'{{ route ('admin.reports.revenue') }}',
   type: "Get",
   data:{start:start, end:end}
  },
  columns: [
   {
    data:'order_date',
    name:'order_date'
   },
   {
    data:'gross_revenue',
    name:'gross_revenue'
   },
   {
    data:'taxes_amount',
    name:'taxes_amount'
   },
   {
    data:'shipping_amount',
    name:'shipping_amount'
   },
   {
    data:'net_revenue',
    name:'net_revenue'
   }
  ]
 });
}

$('#filter').click(function(){
 var start = $('#start-date').val();
 var end = $('#end-date').val();
 if(start != '' &&  end != '')
 {
  $('#sampleTable').DataTable().destroy();
  load_data(start, end);
 }
 else
 {
  alert('Both Date is required');
 }
});

$('#refresh').click(function(){
 $('#start-date').val('');
 $('#end-date').val('');
 $('#sampleTable').DataTable().destroy();
 load_data();
});

    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: `response()->json()` returns... JSON. Not a view

Comment: thank you very much @yainspan can you explain to me how to return a view

Comment: Your code is currently returning a view. `return view('admin.reports.revenue', $this->data);`

Comment: thank you @yainspan sorry I mean what to do if I have to use return response()->json

Comment: @yainspan if I don't use return response()->json I get this "localhost indique:DataTables warning: table id=sampleTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: @yainspan if I make start date and end date and click filter I get DataTables warning: table id=sampleTable - Invalid JSON response and I get the correct result in devtools/Network/preview but not in view in admin/reports/revenue